# Need help in insert statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Here is problem in detail:
[image: Database diagram]

I want to populate the data from source table t1 into destination table t2,t3 and t4. Now,
what i'm doing , first i'm inserting into t2 as :

```
insert into t2(t2.t2Data0, t2.t2Data1)
select t1.t2Data0,t1.t2.Data1 from t1
```

Now, for insertion in t3 and t4, i need some script which can take data for ID col from t2
and rest of columns data from t1.

Any answer will be much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, after you insert your rows into t2, you want to use it's identity field to help populate t3 and t4?

If so, you can just use a `JOIN`:

```
INSERT INTO t3 
SELECT t2.id, t1.t3Data0
FROM t1 
    INNER JOIN t2 ON t1.t2Data0 = t2.tdData0 AND t1.t2Data1 = t2.tdData1

INSERT INTO t4 
SELECT t2.id, t1.t4Data0
FROM t1 
    INNER JOIN t2 ON t1.t2Data0 = t2.tdData0 AND t1.t2Data1 = t2.tdData1
```

Comment: Yes, your assumption is absolutely correct. Thanks sgeddes...:)

Comment: @Prateek -- np, glad I could help!

Answer (score 1):

```
insert  t1
        (c1, c2, c3, c4)
select  coalesce(t2.c1, t3.c1, t4.c1)
,       t2.c2
,       t3.c3
,       t4.c4
from    t2
full outer join    
        t3
on      t2.c1 = t3.c1
full outer join    
        t4
on      t2.c1 = t4.c1
        or t3.c1 = t4.c1
```

Comment: Thanks, Andomar,
Well i think i have not explained my question briefly....
Anyhow edited the question..

Answer (score 1):

I have not tested but I see something like...an after insert trigger on t1 that

a) inserts into t2 (insert into t2(t2.t2Data0, t2.t2Data1) select t1.t2Data0,t2.Data1 from t1 join inserted on t1.id=inserted.id)

b) selects scope identity  (select @T2ID=SCOPE_IDENTITY()

c) inserts into t3 (insert into t3(id, t3data0) select @T2ID, t.t3data0 from t1 join inserted on t1.id=inserted.id)

d) inserts into t4 (insert into t4(id, t4data0) select @T2ID, t.t4data0 from t1 join inserted on t1.id=inserted.id)

```
CREATE TRIGGER trgName ON [t1] 
FOR INSERT 
AS
    declare @T2ID int
    insert into t2(t2.t2Data0, t2.t2Data1) select t1.t2Data0,t2.Data1 from t1 join inserted on t1.id=inserted.id
    select @T2ID=SCOPE_IDENTITY()
    insert into t3(id, t3data0) select @T2ID, t.t3data0 from t1 join inserted on t1.id=inserted.id
    insert into t4(id, t4data0) select @T2ID, t.t4data0 from t1 join inserted on t1.id=inserted.id
end
```

Of course, assuming that this scenario corresponds to your needs

Comment: Good idea, to have a trigger on t2 table & then use magical column(inserted or deleted), in this case inserted. To insert in other two table(t3&t4)..

Comment: Come to think of it, this is not a great idea. Because this only works when you have one transaction. If you have multiple entries in inserted, then this is not going to work. Thanks for the upvote, anyway :)